# Show a list of items belonging to the object

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am learning to use GraphQL and React on someone else's project and I'm trying to understand how it all works together.

There's an object, lets call it a Wall. This wall has a has_many relationship to the object Painting. There already exist component called PaintingList. In the Wall component I want to render a list of all the Paintings that belong to it.

All the queries are created but I just need to render it correctly to the front-end.

This is all very abstract to me right now and I'm sorry if it is unclear..

Wall component:

```
const Wall = ({ Wall }) => {
    return(
        Some data from the wall
        Display all Paintings belonging to the wall
    );
};
```

For every wall I want to display the Paintings that belong to it. Since the Wall has_many Paintings and the Painting has_one wall, does this mean that there's some more simple way to render them, or do I need to compare the ID's?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `Wall` looks like its difficult but, you should use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & return JSX for each painting. Here is an arbitrary example

```
const Wall = ({ Wall }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {Wall.title}

            <ul>
                {Wall.paintings.map(painting => {
                    return <li><img src={painting.src} /></li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```